# Upgrade wordpress core programmatically with PHP

Tags: php, upgrade

**What I want to do**

I want to upgrade Wordpress programmatically to a later version. That I want to do with PHP, lets say from http://www.example.com/?upgrade_wp=true

I already know how to get the URL of the latest version so I don't having any problem with checking for versions or finding the right URL.

**Answers I want**

- A link to a tutorial of how this is done.
- A plugin that does this and not so much more.
- A hint to the functions that I need to use.

**Answers I don't want**

- The way to do it with SVN or subversion.
- Answers containing Wordpress MU.
- How to manually doing this.
- How to do this with other code than PHP.

Comment: Why would you want to install a plugin that does something WP already does out of the box?

Comment: Absent some example of a non-niche use case, Close-voted as **too localized**.

Comment: *Answers I want/don't want* = invitation for being sarcastic, but I'll refrain myself & instead some useful info: study how InfiniteWP does it...

Comment: @brasofilo Thanks! InfiniteWP was just what I was going to build. Now I don't need to...

Comment: @ChipBennett How can update Wordpress from the outside be too localized? Many people have done that. Just not that many people show their code like InfiniteWP.

Comment: @moraleida My goal was to have some sort of panel for administrating many sites at the same time. However, InfiniteWP solved that problem.

Comment: Jens, glad to hear! The way you posed your question seemed that you wanted to do it in a single site, which is a bit odd... And being well written and formated no one could guess you had another goal, hence the critics and downvotes... best regards..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A hint to the functions that I need to use.

I'm not sure why you'll want to mimic WP's default behavior, but most of the update logic lies on `wp-admin/update-core.php`

Check for `do_core_upgrade()`.

Comment: For my question this is the right answer. Thanks! However I solved the problem by using InfiniteWP. It's a self hosted admin for administrating multiple sites at the same time. That way I don't need to build it myself.

Answer (score 2):

The trigger function for core update seems to be [`wp_update_core()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_update_core/), which calls `Core_Upgrader` class ([source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.3/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php#L919)).